# Mysql-php mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $avg_pgt = mysql_query("SELECT avg(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)),min(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)), max(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned) FROM `table_name` WHERE server_time BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59'");

        $row_all = mysql_fetch_array($avg_pgt);         
        $string_avg = (string)$row_all[0];      
        echo $string_avg;
```

It gives an error mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be a resource boolean given in the code

Comment: If this is new code: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and [are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the red box? Learn about [prepared statements](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: That means there is some problem in your query, always use `die(mysql_error());`.

Answer (score 1):

```
max(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)
```

Is missing a ) at the end, This would work:

```
    $avg_pgt = mysql_query("SELECT avg(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)),min(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)), max(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)) FROM `table_name` WHERE server_time BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59'");

    $row_all = mysql_fetch_array($avg_pgt);         
    $string_avg = (string)$row_all[0];      
    echo $string_avg;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$avg_pgt = mysql_query("SELECT avg(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)),min(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)), max(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned) FROM `table_name` WHERE server_time BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59'");
```

This query is failing and `mysql_query` is returning `false`. Check if your query is fine and returns results elsewhere. Is `table_name` really the name of your table?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the mysql_* functions since they are being deprecated since php5.

Use PDO or mysqli!

From the [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) documentation page:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not
>   have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

Call [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `)` at `max(convert(custom_var_v1,unsigned)`

mysql_* functions are dprecated, use mysqli_ or PDO